# How can I restrict google login to my company's email domain (@company.com) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth

**Question**

What is the best way to prevent users from using an email address that does not end in @mycompany.com from logging in to our internal app through Google auth?

I am new in flutter so can someone provide me the references or tutorial on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match user email with regex if true then company email else not company email.

RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[mycompanyname.com]")

Comment: Can you please elaborate me to implement this using Google Oauth ?